# NumberFormatException when i try to toDouble() the String, even when the input String is a valid representation of a Double

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

i got an issue with my Code. Im using Android Studio with Kotlin.
So, i got an EditText-field with an input-type="numberDecimal".

when i try to convert that string to a Double:

```
val preis = etProduktGekauftPreis.text.toString().toDouble()
```

and try to create a new Object with the "preis"

```
val produkt = Produkt(name, anzahl.toInt(), preis)
```

For example im getting the error: NumberFormatException: For input string: "3.00"

The string is a valid representation of a number or not? why do i keep getting this Error?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Its due to your locale, in german it would be expected to give "3,00" instead of "3.00". You would need to parse the string correctly/differently for example by replacing the comma based on what ever possible locales you support or by removing the comma converting to double then dividing by 100